# How to do enum in Extjs4.1 model?

Tags: extjs, enums, extjs4.1

I would like to assign an enum field in model. 
Something like this:

```
fields:[
    {name:'method', type:'string', enum:['method1', 'method2', 'method3']}
]
```

And I want other components are able to know how many members in the enum, or even can access the enum members by a number.(just like using Array)

Does ExtJS4.1 have any feature like that? I cannot find anything like that in the api.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this, if yes, are you able to post a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it is not straightforward.

If you look at [these docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type), you'll see that there's no enum option.

However, as the same docs suggest, you can create your own data types. So you can simulate an enum there. I suggest you look at the implementation of existing types (date, for example) to see how this is done.

Comment: All right. It seems I should do it by myself. Thank your for answering.